# FF7 Intergrade - Standalone or mid game?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

**Summary**:  Is Final Fantasy 7 Remake Intergrade playable in the main storyline, or does it absolutely have to be accessed outside of the primary game?

**Details**:  I have FF7:RM and have played through it already, but was about to start a NG+ when Intergrade was announced/released.  I put off my NG+ until I got ahold of it.  When starting it up, I was presented with the option of playing Yuffie's story just...outright.  My problem is that it has been a solid *year* since I last played FF7:RM, and could use a refresher on it.

**Question**:  Can I start a "new game plus" to play FF7:RM from the start, and halfway through, be introduced to Yuffi, and play her missions, then have it transition back to the main game?

**Final wrap up** :  Honestly I forgot/got out of practice many of the mechanics, details, controls, etc of the main game, and the first like, 30 minutes of Intergrade, I was absolutely getting demolished - thinking it would be nice for me to have that slow re-introduction, and then while I'm neck deep in the mechanics, play through intergrade...

Answer (score 2):

> Can I start a "new game plus" to play FF7:RM from the start, and halfway through, be introduced to Yuffi, and play her missions, then have it transition back to the main game?

Yes, you are able to play Yuffi's storyline independently from the main story line. If you have purchased, the INTERmission episode, there will be a separate title screen menu to play this campaign

> Once EPISODE INTERmission Yuffie DLC is downloaded, you will be able to start the episode from the main menu of the PS5 version of FF7 Remake (Intergrade). Simply press the R2 button to see the EPISODE INTERmission title screen.
>
> [Source](https://www.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-7-remake/How_to_Start_EPISODE_INTERmission_Yuffie_DLC)